# Notice Message: Undefined Index (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

**Tenho um formulário onde é carregado dois selects multiplos, aqui o código:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="categorias[]">Selecione a(s) categoria(s) referente(s) a foto:</label>
                        <select name="categorias[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $categoria['idCategoria'] ?>"><?= $categoria['dscCategoria'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subcategorias[]">Selecione a(s) subcategoria(s) referente(s) a foto:</label>
                        <select name="subcategorias[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php foreach ($subcategorias as $subcategoria) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $subcategoria['idSubcategoria'] ?>"><?= $subcategoria['dscSubcategoria'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

**O código do controller que faz o tratamento desta view é o seguinte:**

```
$this->load->model('admin/tbdcategoria');
    $lista['categorias'] = $this->tbdcategoria->listarCategorias();
    $dados['categorias'] = array('categorias' => $lista['categorias']);

    $this->load->model('admin/tbdsubcategoria');
    $lista['subcategorias'] = $this->tbdsubcategoria->listarSubcategorias();
    $dados['subcategorias'] = array('subcategorias' => $lista['subcategorias']);

    $this->load->view('layout/admin/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('admin/upload_fotos', $dados); 
    $this->load->view('layout/admin/footer');
```

**O código dos models para exibição dos dados é o seguinte:**

```
function listarCategorias()
{
    return $this->db->get('tbdcategoria')->result_array();
}
function listarSubcategorias()
{
    return $this->db->get('tbdsubcategoria')->result_array();
}
```

**O problema é o seguinte, na exibição ao invés de carregar as categorias / subcategorias cadastradas no banco, está retornando "Undefined Index"**

[image]

Comment: Facilita para a gente, qual a linha exata que esta gerando esse erro ?

Comment: <option value="<?= $categoria['idCategoria'] ?>"><?= $categoria['dscCategoria'] ?></option>

<option value="<?= $subcategoria['idSubcategoria'] ?>"><?= $subcategoria['dscSubcategoria'] ?></option>

Nessas 2 está retornando index indefinido

Comment: Ja verificou se esta montando esses dados ? tentou fazer um var_dump e talz para ter certeza ?

Comment: Esse erro é bem explicativo, você esta tentando utilizar uma chave do array que não existe

Comment: antes de utilizar a chave de um array, faz uma verificação se essa chave existe.

Comment: O var_dump está retornando "NULL"

Comment: Mas existe, porque se eu deixo apenas um select buscando dados de um model apenas, ele carrega, a partir do momento que chamo outro select com outro model, ele passa a não carregar nem um nem outro

Comment: Pelo que reparei, se eu passo pro exemplo $lista['categorias'] não funciona, se eu passar apenas $lista, ele funciona. Mas aí não vou conseguir nunca carregar dados no meu outro select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consegui resolver, vou deixar aqui o que fiz, caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema.**

**Minha view ficou assim:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="categorias[]">Selecione a(s) categoria(s) referente(s) a foto:</label>
                        <select name="categorias[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php foreach ($listarCategorias->result() as $row) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row->idCategoria; ?>"><?php echo $row->dscCategoria; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subcategorias[]">Selecione a(s) subcategoria(s) referente(s) a foto:</label>
                        <select name="subcategorias[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                            <?php foreach ($listarSubcategorias->result() as $row) : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row->idSubcategoria; ?>"><?php echo $row->dscSubcategoria; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

**Meu controller ficou assim:**

```
$this->load->model('admin/tbdcategoria');
    $dados["listarCategorias"] = $this->tbdcategoria->listarCategorias();

    $this->load->model('admin/tbdsubcategoria');
    $dados["listarSubcategorias"] = $this->tbdsubcategoria->listarSubcategorias();

    $this->load->view('layout/admin/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('admin/upload_fotos', $dados); 
    $this->load->view('layout/admin/footer');
```

**Meu model ficou assim:**

```
function listarCategorias()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("tbdcategoria");

    return $query;
}
function listarSubcategorias()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("tbdsubcategoria");

    return $query;
}
```